# Remove the Only DIV tags from string without contents in div tags using c#

Tags: c#, html

Remove the DIV tags from string without contents in div tags.

Input: `<Div>test</Div>\r\n<Div>for IE</DIV>`

Output: `test\r\n for IE`

Answer (score 4):

This expression will get the inner contents:

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    resultString = Regex.Match(part, "(?<=\")(.*)(?=\")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase |     RegexOptions.Multiline).Value;
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var output = input.Replace("<div>", "").Replace("</div>", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Check String.replace method 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx

You could replace `<div>` and `</div>` strings with ''

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion for you. Take this regular expression `\</?Div\>` and use it like that:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\</?Div\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var newString = regex.Replace(stringToReplace, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = "yourstring".Replace("<DIV>", "").Replace("</Div>", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just try the simplest thing based on the current data.

```
var str = "<div>test</div>\r\n<div>for IE</div>";

var output = str.Replace("<div>",string.Empty).Replace("</div>",string.Empty);
```

Or in more complex cases where you have attributes on the div you might want to use Regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string input = @"<Div>test</Div>\r\n<Div>for IE</DIV>";
 string pattern = @"\<(\/)*(Div){1}\>";
 string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, String.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```